# Object array can't add items on React chips from material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm with a little issue here right now with Material-UI chips component. I have a select with a list of users. When you select a user, a chip with his number appears right below the form. Everything works just fine but the chips are overwriting, not adding the new ones. Here my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';

export default function Test(){
   const [chipData, setChipData] = React.useState([]);
   const userArray = [
      {key: 1, label: name1},
      {kel: 2, label: name2}
   ];
   const [userValue, setUserValue] = React.useState('');

   // This come from the select form onChange
   const handleSelect = (e) => {
      setUserValue(e.target.value);
      setChipData([...chipData, {key: e.target.value, label: e.target.value}]);
   }

   const handleDelete = chipToDelete => () => {
      setChipData(chips => chips.filter(chips => chips.key !== chipToDelete.key));
   }

   return(
      <div>
      <TextField
         select
         value={userValue}
         onChange={e => handleSelect(e)}
      >
         {userArray.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option.key} value={option.label}>
               {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
         ))}
      </TextField>
      {chipData.map(data => {
         return(
            <Chip
               key={data.key}
               label={data.label}
               onDelete={handleDelete(data)}
            />
         );
      })}
      </div>
   );
}
```

I tried with something like `chipData.push({data...})` that works just fine, but do not allow me to add more items if I delete any of them. With the code above the chips are just overwriting the one clicked before and do not add to the array.

Comment: Take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-qv0rv), I am not sure how you have created the chip component, do you have close icon for deleting chip? Please post code for rendering select.

Comment: Question updated with the post code. The chips is not inside the select like in codesandbox. Tried to figure out how to do it but I couldn't. Chips still overwriting instead of adding.

Answer (score 0):

Online Example, please validate if you have the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-n7kbp
only edited key render values:

```
{chipData.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <Chip
            key={data.key + index}
            label={data.label}
            onDelete={handleDelete(data)}
          />
        );
      })}
```

Comment: The chips still overwriting instead of adding new ones. I think this is something with the handleSelect function.

Comment: i edited answer with example with your similar code, please explain where is the problem, Only edited  key values  for chips with index.

Comment: Even for me it is [working](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-dawn-v5l1q)